# Correlated subquery nested (2nd order) cannot access main query (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do something like this

EDIT - The whole query.

```
SELECT *
FROM ride
WHERE
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT mobile FROM contacts WHERE `contacts`.`user_mobile` =  '".$user_mobile."'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DISTINCT mobile FROM contacts WHERE `contacts`.`user_mobile` = `ride`.`user_mobile`
    ) AS c
) > 1
AND ( 
    distance_geo('".$start_lat."', '".$start_long."', starting_lat, starting_long) < '".$start_radius."'
    OR id IN (
        SELECT rideid FROM routept WHERE 
        distance_geo('".$start_lat."', '".$start_long."', starting_lat, starting_long) < '".$start_radius."'
    )
)
AND ( 
    distance_geo('".$end_lat."', '".$end_long."', end_lat, end_long) < '".$end_radius."'
    OR id IN (
        SELECT rideid FROM routept WHERE 
        distance_geo('".$start_lat."', '".$start_long."', starting_lat, starting_long) < '".$end_radius."'
    )
)
AND availablity >= 1
AND start_time BETWEEN '".$start_after."' AND '".$start_before."'
AND start_time > NOW()
ORDER BY start_time ASC"
```

But, I cannot be able to do it. I am getting

```
Unknown column 'ride.user_mobile' in 'where clause'
```

I think it cannot be accessed within nested subqueries. I need a workaround for this please. I have more conditions in this where clause, but I am posting only the troubling part!

Comment: Yea you are right _it cannot be accessed within nested subqueries._

Comment: But I need a solution for the same. How can I make to work something like this?

Comment: Could you explaine your logic in query because it difficult to understand. thanks

Comment: I have a table ride. I have another table contact where a name, number and user_mobile is stored. There are few number of contact details saved for every user_mobile. The user_mobile is present in ride also. I want to select the count of mutual contacts between the user_mobile of the ride and user_mobile of the working user, which I am providing as PHP variable.

Comment: distance_geo this is your function ?

Comment: Yes. It takes 2 geo pos (lat, long), and return the air distance between them in KM.

Comment: Thank you, What was wrong ?

Comment: It gave some ambiguous error. Adding tablename.column in sub query fixed it. Thats all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one, and let me know

```
Select  contacts.user_mobile  // here you can add other columns
        , Count(*) as Total
From    ride 
  JOIN mobile On contacts.user_mobile = ride.user_mobile
Where contacts.user_mobile = ".$user_mobile."
Group By contacts.user_mobile
Having Total > 1
```

**Update**

Querty above this is your base, now just add other condition in Where clause

```
Select  contacts.user_mobile  // here you can add other columns
        , Count(*) as Total
From    ride 
  JOIN mobile On contacts.user_mobile = ride.user_mobile
Where contacts.user_mobile = ".$user_mobile." 
    AND  distance_geo('".$start_lat."', '".$start_long."', 
            starting_lat, starting_long) < '".$start_radius."'
    OR ride.id IN (
        SELECT  rideid 
        FROM    routept 
        WHERE   distance_geo('".$start_lat."', '".$start_long."', 
                starting_lat, starting_long) < '".$start_radius."')
    AND  distance_geo('".$end_lat."', '".$end_long."', 
            end_lat, end_long) < '".$end_radius."'
    OR ride.id IN (
        SELECT  rideid 
        FROM    routept 
        WHERE distance_geo('".$start_lat."', '".$start_long."', 
                starting_lat, starting_long) < '".$end_radius."')
    AND ride.availablity >= 1
    AND ride.start_time BETWEEN '".$start_after."' AND '".$start_before."'
    AND ride.start_time > NOW()
Group By contacts.user_mobile
Having Total > 1
Order BY ride.start_time ASC"
```

Comment: I have updated the entire query! I am new to SQL help around to get it done, please. Thanks.

Comment: In the same description I said earlier, I now have other criteria in WHERE caluse. I want an workaround for this now.

Comment: It is giving me 0 results always! :( @The

Answer (score 0):

@The gave me a working solution!

WORKING SOLUTION:

```
SELECT  contacts.user_mobile , ride.id, ride.user_mobile, ride.vehicle_no, ride.availablity, ride.ride_type, ride.starting_lat,
                        ride.starting_long, ride.starting_addr, ride.start_city, ride.end_lat, ride.end_long, ride.end_addr, ride.end_city,
                        ride.vehicle_ac, ride.status, ride.rent, ride.start_time, ride.dept_time,
                        COUNT(*) as Total
                FROM ride 
                    JOIN contacts ON contacts.user_mobile = ride.user_mobile
                WHERE contacts.user_mobile = ".$user_mobile."
                AND ( 
                    distance_geo('".$start_lat."', '".$start_long."', ride.starting_lat, ride.starting_long) < '".$start_radius."'
                    OR ride.id IN (
                        SELECT rideid FROM routept WHERE 
                        distance_geo('".$start_lat."', '".$start_long."', ride.starting_lat, ride.starting_long) < '".$start_radius."'
                    )
                )
                AND ( 
                    distance_geo('".$end_lat."', '".$end_long."', ride.end_lat, ride.end_long) < '".$end_radius."'
                    OR ride.id IN (
                        SELECT rideid FROM routept WHERE 
                        distance_geo('".$start_lat."', '".$start_long."', ride.end_lat, ride.end_long) < '".$end_radius."'
                    )
                )
                AND ride.availablity >= 1
                AND ride.start_time BETWEEN '".$start_after."' AND '".$start_before."'
                AND ride.start_time > NOW()
                GROUP BY contacts.user_mobile
                HAVING Total > 1
                ORDER BY ride.start_time ASC"
```

Thanks @The.